# how to create " Doted Line step indicators" in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, indicator

I'm developing on a app, In (Flutter)

Im trying to build a step bar with dot-line indicator but not able to do so, the material I was able to get from searching was only simple step indicator not with dot-line, not what like I want as showen in screenshot below could someone help me how to build this indicator in Flutter with code! Thank you. [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Just create a stack with a divider under the circle icons. Please try this code

[image: Preview]

```dart
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<int> steps = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF5F5F7),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200.0,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 180.0,
                child: Divider(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  thickness: 2,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  for (var step in steps)
                    Icon(
                      Icons.circle,
                      color: step == 1 ? Colors.redAccent[400] : Colors.grey,
                      size: step == 1 ? 24.0 : 16.0,
                    )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can improve it by adding micro-interactions like animations

Comment: Ok I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: I would do that thanks brother you really helped I appreciate it. Last thing bro In the screenshot the circle it has an outline colors of light-pink and in-side is transparent could enlighten me on that to!

Comment: Great! You can change the icon type based on the selected step

Comment: Also, instead of using icons. You can create the outline icon with fill color with a container. Add radius and border to it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as following:
Stack which contains

1. Container with height 1 and width that you want
2. Row which has inside 5 containers one for each indicator with decoration that you want for the circle

Then declare a variable with a type of integer and set it's value on next
then you can check if indecator == 0 ==> change the decoration of first container >> if indecator == 1 ==> change the decoration of second container ... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stepper widget. See [this article](https://developer.school/flutter-how-to-use-the-stepper-widget/).